# ERROR: b.forEach is not a function with uigrid [Angular]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am making a grid in AngularJS with Angular UI Grid and the console printing this error:

```
error: b.forEach is not a function
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

```
  vm.detalleVirtuales.paginationOptions = {pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 500, sort: null};
  vm.detalleVirtuales = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableGridMenu: true,
      enableSelectAll: true,
      showGridFooter: true,
      paginationPageSizes: [500, 1000, 3000, 5000],
      paginationPageSize: 500,
      useExternalPagination: true,
      columnDefs: columDefo,
      useExternalSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableGridMenu: true,
      enableSelectAll: true,
      enableColumnMenus: true,
      exporterCsvFilename: "Detalle_virtuales.csv",
      exporterExcelFilename: 'Detalle_virtuales.xlsx',
      exporterExcelSheetName: 'Detalle_virtuales',
      exporterOlderExcelCompatibility: true,
      showColumnFooter: true
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet which reproduces the error.

Comment: probably b is not an array. u might want to check.